# How to use the font i imported from the css file

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is the code I added in my css style sheet:

```
        @font-face 
{
        font-family: 'space_rangerregular';
        src: url('spaceranger-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('spaceranger-webfont.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

I associated this with h6:

```
h6{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family:"Space Ranger Regular", serif;
}
```

Then in my HTML file (i linked the css sheet ) i did:

```
<h6>Test</h6>
```

However my code doesn't display the font. Whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same value that you assigned to `font-family` in the `@font-face` section for `font-family` where you want to use it. So, for your h6:

```css
h6{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: space_rangerregular, serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `font-face` you set the `font-family` to name that font. So, in your CSS you need to call that font using the name you enter in `font-family`. But you need to put that name inside a quotation marks. So:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'space_rangerregular'; // Name of your font
  src: url('spaceranger-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('spaceranger-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

h6{
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'space_rangerregular', serif; // Call the SAME name here
}
```

Comment: Names for `font-family` only need to be quoted if they are not valid CSS identifiers. Doesn't hurt to use them, and is probably good practice to use them if in doubt, but they're not required for `space_rangerregular`.